# Input validation recursive function (want positive integer) fails to work when negative integer is input

Tags: c, scanf

```
int get_num_order(){
    char term;
    int input;
    printf("Please enter the number of items you want to order: ");
    if(scanf(" %d%c", &input, &term) != 2 || term != '\n' || input < 0){
        // printf("%d", input);
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        get_num_order();
    }
    else{
        // printf("%d", input);
        return input;
    }
    
}
```

I've been following various tutorials on the internet, and this one worked the best so far. It successfully handles decimals, letters, and whitespace, but it gets stuck at negative numbers. The program just pauses. I'm not sure what the issue is, help?

Comment: If need more information let me know I will add it in asap

Comment: What input do you provide, what behaviour do you expect, what do you get? What does "fals to work" mean in detail?

Comment: You mention a loop but instead you are calling your function recursivle. That looks terrible inefficient. Why don't you use a loop if you seem to be aware there should be a loop?

Comment: Recursive function calls need to capture the return values...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the respons. The input I provide: any kind such as 'a', 10, 1.8, 'a7', -7, 0. What I want my code to do: repeat until an integer > 0 is input, ask for input. Output: return the integer to my main function. I get the correct expected behavior until a negative number is input. Then the program just stops and does not continue. I want to solve that issue @Gerhardh

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title, I'll change it to recursive. I don't know which is more efficient. I know how to use loops/functions, but whichever i use I still have the negative input problem. I thought that my `input<0` would solve the issue but it didn't. . ?

Comment: @Fe2O3 how should I implement that? :)

Comment: The function is supposed to return an int... Look at the code. See the function call that does nothing with the return value from the function call? Think about what it might do with the returned value instead of ignoring it...

Comment: Your compiler should even warn you about not returning a value in a non-void function on all information flows. If not, increase warning level. For GCC use -`Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: If you use a loop instead of recursion you cannot have the same error of not returning result of recursive call. That must be another error

Comment: Did you check in a debugger that it "does nothing"? I would rather expect it ro return to caller but not returning any useful vale. Without a complete example it is hard to tell why you think it might "do nothing"

Comment: Ok I think I will change my approach to just a loop since I'm not very good at using functions yet and I'm not exactly sure what you mean ahhh. I think I will try again with a loop and if i still can't then I'll make a new question with more information and context. Thanks for all the guidance the two of you :) but do you have any tips about why my `input<0` condition doesn't help check? Because for all other inputs, the code works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%*[^\n]");` was blocking the function after entering a negative number. If the first `scanf` read the negative number and a newline, there was nothing in the buffer to remove.
This seems to work.

```
int get_num_order(){
    char term = 0;
    int input = 0;
    printf("Please enter the number of items you want to order: ");
    if(scanf("%d%c", &input, &term) != 2 || term != '\n' || input < 0){
        // printf("\t%d\n", input);
        if ( term != '\n') {
            scanf("%*[^\n]"); // remove all from buffer to newline
        }
        input = get_num_order();
    }
    return input;
}
```